# softether VPN Server can't install

Tags: vpn, checkinstall

I will get this error after I accepted all the terms
https://pastebin.com/DZmr7HPm
Sorry for the chinese

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using   Ubuntu Linux 17.10